# Are there any open source Java reflection utilities or jars?

Tags: java, reflection

Is there any open source utility or jar for handling reflection in java?

I am passing methods Dynamically to a class and I would like to fetch the return value.

For Example:

```
class Department {
    String name ;
    Employee[] employees;
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public  Employee[] getEmployes() {
        return employees;

    }
}
```

I would like to print all the employees to the console output but instead getting it at run-time like this:

```
Department dept = new Department();
// add employees..

getEmployeeNames(dept,"getEmployees.getAddress.getStreet");
// So the user says they want employee street, but we don't know that
// until run-tme.
```

Is there any opensource on reflection to accommodate something like this?

Comment: `getEmployes()` returns an array? There will be no method `getAddress()` on an `[]`..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of thing always rings design alarm bells when I see it.

That being said, I usually think that JXPath ( http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/users-guide.html ) is the most reasonable solution for that type of problem if it can't be solved in a more engineered way:

```
import org.apache.commons.jxpath.JXPathContext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 */
public class JXPather {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Department d = new Department();
        d.employees.add(new Employee(new Address("wherever a")));
        d.employees.add(new Employee(new Address("wherever b")));
        d.employees.add(new Employee(new Address("wherever c")));
        d.employees.add(new Employee(new Address("wherever def")));

        JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(d);
        // access matched xpath objects by iterating over them
        for (Iterator iterator = context.iterate("/employees/address/street"); iterator.hasNext();) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }

        // or directly via standard xpath expressions

        System.out.println("street of third employee is: "+context.getValue("/employees[3]/address/street"));

        // supports most (or all ?) xpath expressions

        for (Iterator iterator = context.iterate("/employees/address/street[string-length(.) > 11]"); iterator.hasNext();) {
            System.out.println("street length longer than 11 c'ars:"+iterator.next());
        }
    }

    static public class Department {
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
            return employees;
        }
    }

    static public class Employee {
        Address address;
        Employee(Address address) {
            this.address = address;
        }
        public Address getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

    }

    static public class Address {
        String street;
        Address(String street) {
            this.street = street;
        }
        public String getStreet() {
            return street;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That is a very interesting approach. I didn't know JXPath up until now. Looks very nice!

Answer (score 20):

Apart from using Apache BeanUtils or using the `java.lang.reflect` API directly, as others suggested, you could also use [jOOR](http://code.google.com/p/joor/), which I created to decrease the verbosity of using reflection in Java. Your example could then be implemented like this:

```
Employee[] employees = on(department).call("getEmployees").get();

for (Employee employee : employees) {
  Street street = on(employee).call("getAddress").call("getStreet").get();
  System.out.println(street);
}
```

The same example with normal reflection in Java:

```
try {
  Method m1 = department.getClass().getMethod("getEmployees");
  Employee employees = (Employee[]) m1.invoke(department);

  for (Employee employee : employees) {
    Method m2 = employee.getClass().getMethod("getAddress");
    Address address = (Address) m2.invoke(employee);

    Method m3 = address.getClass().getMethod("getStreet");
    Street street = (Street) m3.invoke(address);

    System.out.println(street);
  }
}

// There are many checked exceptions that you are likely to ignore anyway 
catch (Exception ignore) {

  // ... or maybe just wrap in your preferred runtime exception:
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Also, jOOR wraps the `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` functionality in a more convenient way:

```
interface StringProxy {
  String mySubString(int beginIndex);
}

// You can easily create a proxy of a custom type to a jOOR-wrapped object
String substring = on("java.lang.String")
                    .create("Hello World")
                    .as(StringProxy.class)
                    .mySubString(6);
```

Comment: Looks very good, but are you sure it's a good idea to generify the cast away in the get() methods? I assume the signature is `<T> T get()`, that might cause more trouble than a good old honest cast at the call site.

Comment: @MartinProbst: Yes, you're right about the signature. I don't think it's such a bad idea. `java.util.Collections` has a couple of similar cases...

Comment: @LukasEder: the cases in java.util.Collections only concern the generic type of the returned collection, which does not exist at runtime (because of erasure). As the returned collections are immutable, that can never lead to an error, and the difference isn't even observable, so the casts are always safe.

Comment: @MartinProbst: Hmm, you're right. I hadn't thought about it this way. I was looking at `Collections.reverseOrder()` too, but in the end, that reverse ordering comparator can safely handle any type, too. I guess, I'll correct the jOOR API

Answer (score 1):

you can use apache beanutils: http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/

Answer (score 1):

You can use some third-party library as others suggest or can do the trick manually yourself, it is not so hard. The following example should illustrate the way one could take:

```
class Department {
  Integer[] employees;
  public void setEmployes(Integer[] employees) { this.employees = employees; }
  public Integer[] getEmployees() { return employees; }
}

Department dept = new Department();
dept.setEmployes(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3});
Method mEmploees = Department.class.getMethod("getEmployees", new Class[] {});
Object o = mEmploees.invoke(dept, new Object[] {});
Integer[] employees = (Integer[])o;
System.out.println(employees[0].doubleValue());;
```