# How to obtain the schema of a Java class stored in Oracle Database

Tags: java, oracle

I have an Oracle database application, consisting of several types of objects, e.g. tables, PL/SQL packages, and Java classes. These objects are required to be installed in the same schema, but the actual name of the schema is not fixed.
Let's say I want to run a query on one of the tables from Java.

The application can be called by other users than the schema owner, so the installation schema is not the default schema of the session. Thus, I need to prefix the table name with the installation schema. Is there a way to obtain the answer to the question "In which schema is this class installed?" from a method in the class?

Due to the number of objects involved and due to the fact that most of them are private to the application, creating synonyms in the schema of every application user (or public ones) is not an option.

I have come up with the following kludge:
As part of the installation script, I have the following command:

```
create or replace java resource named "inst.properties" using clob
select to_clob('InstSchema='||sys_context('userenv','current_schema')) from dual;
/
```

I can then use the class loader of a given class to load this resource into a `Properties` object, and use that to get the schema that was used at installation time. This is a kludge, because it may be invalidated, e.g. by someone exporting the schema and importing it with a new name without updating the property file.

The above kludge works because the class loader associated with a class will look first in the schema of that class, and thus get the resource in that schema. Since the class loader can do this, there must be a way it can know the schema of the class. And if there is such a way, then it should be possible to get that information. The question is how.

Comment: What did you do about that; what are your researches; what are your tryings?

Comment: Have you considered using a login trigger to [set the end-user's `current_schema` to the application schema](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6265422366927)?

Comment: This is database with many different applications. Changing `current_schema` is not acceptable.

Comment: What database and Java version?

Comment: Database 11.2.0.4, Java 1.6u43.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a vague answer, but the best I can do here is give you a couple of hints without a lot more research.

The way Oracle loads classes is specified by a class resolver at load time:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chtwo.htm#BABGJCAJ

So one way to get the schema would be to get at the resolver somehow and introspect it to figure out which schema it loaded first, since it starts with the definer schema.

There's also a facility for sharing class metadata in a special table:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/appendixb.htm#BGBBBJAE

I have no idea how that table works, but I'd guess that it provides the schema as a system property.

The other way to do it from pure Java would be to get a `DatabaseMetaData` object and then look for the object there.  The `ResultSet` it gives you back would have the name of the schema.

Comment: I must admit that I have no experience using reflection, so I have no clue how to implement it, but it seems the right way to go.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385003/are-there-any-open-source-java-reflection-utilities-or-jars) might be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear but if you need the owner of a table you can query ALL_TABLES

Example:

```
select OWNER, TABLE_NAME, TABLESPACE_NAME
from ALL_TABLES
where TABLE_NAME like '%what you want%'
```

Comment: I can not use that solution. There may be several installations of the application of one database, e.g. a productive and a test version.